# How to make an iOS app, that perform function in the background with some interval?

Tags: ios, xcode, timer

I want make my iOS app, that can every 5 minutes perform a specific function. How to do it?
A function is simple, like

```
batter = 95; // will be calculated.. every time is differ
[UIApplication sharedApplication].applicationIconBadgeNumber = batter;
```

I need to make timer for it, in background

Comment: Use NSTimer and invoke a predefined method for a predefined time interval.

Comment: Stavash: the NSTimer will invalidate when the application enters the background.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't do this in the background unless your app fall in one of the categories: VOIP, audio playback or location update. If you places timers they will become invalids when the application goes to the background.

Comment: Also all `NSTimer` object will be invalidated when an app enters the background.

Comment: can you give me alternatives?

Comment: Apple suggest that you Push notification do achieve this, if this is something your app can not do then you are out of luck. Is suggest reading:[Background Execution and Multitasking](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/ManagingYourApplicationsFlow/ManagingYourApplicationsFlow.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007072-CH4-SW24)

Comment: you can run your application in the background for 10 minutes maximum, as @rckoenes suggest you has to use push notification to accomplish this

Comment: THere is no alternative. Using push notification is not feasible in your situation - sending a push notification every 5 minutes would be a ridiculous thing to do.

Answer (score 0):

have a timer declared like so in my **.h file:**

```
NSTimer *MyTimer;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSTimer *MyTimer;
```

Then on the **.m file,** I declared it like so:

```
UIBackgroundTaskIdentifier BackGroundTask;
UIApplication  *app = [UIApplication sharedApplication];
BackGroundTask = [app beginBackgroundTaskWithExpirationHandler:^{
    [app endBackgroundTask:BackGroundTask]; 
}];
self.MyTimer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:5 target:self
selector:@selector(TimerMethod) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
```

**Following is Timer Method that call at every 5 sec.:**

```
 -(void)TimerMethod 
   {
        batter = 95; // will be calculated.. every time is differ
    [UIApplication sharedApplication].applicationIconBadgeNumber = batter;

    }
```

Comment: beware that this way you will only be able to keep it running for a maximum of 10min. as per Appele documentation.